# read data from String in C

Tags: c, string

Hello i need a program that read a string from an text 
   file which it has the form(abc12345). I need to read 
    only the number because i need to modify that number. 
    Then i need to make again the string with the modifyed number. 
    Ex  input: abcd12345 output: abcd12346
    I only know to read the entire line(string) from file.
    I was thinking that maybe if i split the string in 2 strings
    one with characters and the other with numbers, but i dont know to do that.

Here is the code i made:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char c[20];
    FILE *in,*out;
    out=fopen("out.txt","w");

    if ((in=fopen("in.txt","r"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error! opening file");
        exit(1);
    }

    fscanf(in,"%20s",c);
    printf("String that was read: %s",c);
    fprintf(out,"%s",c);
    fclose(in);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the string prefix is always the same, such as `abcd` then you can use `sscanf(c, "abcd%d", &val)` change `val`, then do `printf("abcd%d", val)`.

Comment: "I was thinking that maybe if i split the string in 2 strings one with characters and the other with numbers" -- excellent idea! "But i dont know to do that." -- by looking for the first decimal digit in the string?

Comment: Look into `ctype.h`.  It has functions you can use like `isalpha()` and `isdigit()`.  Then just manually go through the string, look for where it changes from alpha to digit, and use that index to have your two split strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for answers guys.This is the final version of the code:
Input file has:
 **abcd123456789456789**
Output file has: 
**abcd123456789456789

abcd123456789456790

abcd123456789456791

abcd123456789456792**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 int main(){
 char c[20];
 char *constant;
 char *variable;
 int tmp;

FILE *in,*out;
in=fopen("in.txt","r");

if(in==NULL){
    printf("Error opening file");
    return(1);//error
            }
else{
    fgets(c,20,in);
    }
fclose(in);

out=fopen("out.txt","w");
fprintf(out,"%s\n",c);

variable=&c[11];//set the start position of pointer variable
c[20]=0;//set the end position

tmp=atoi(variable);

int variable2,variable3,variable4;
char buffer2[9],buffer3[9],buffer4[9];

variable2=tmp+1;
variable3=tmp+2;
variable4=tmp+3;

itoa(variable2,buffer2,10);//in base hexa,10;
itoa(variable3,buffer3,10);
itoa(variable4,buffer4,10);

constant=&c[0];//set start position of pointer constant
c[11]=0;



fprintf(out,"%s%s\n",constant,buffer2);
fprintf(out,"%s%s\n",constant,buffer3);
fprintf(out,"%s%s",constant,buffer4);
fclose(out);
return(0);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
char S[SIZE];
char a[SIZE];
int b = 0;
char c[SIZE];
scanf("%s", S);

int l = strlen(S);
int i = 0;
while (!isdigit(S[i])) {
    a[i] = S[i];
    i++;
}
a[i] = '\0';

while (i < l) {
    b = b * 10 + S[i] - '0';
    i++;
}

b++;
printf("n = %d\n", b);

sprintf(c, "%s%d", a, b);
printf("%s\n", c);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *strinc(const char *str, int d){
    char wk[12];//12:int need size
    char *p;
    int len, d_len, c;

    c = len = strlen(str);
    while(isdigit(str[--c]));
    ++c;
    d += strtol(&str[c], NULL, 10);
    if(d<0) d = 0;
    d_len = sprintf(wk, "%d", d);
    p = malloc((c+d_len+1)*sizeof(char));
    strncpy(p, str, c);
    p[c]='\0';
    return strcat(p, wk);
}

int main(void){//DEMO
    char *str_num1 ="abc12345";
    char *incstr, *decstr;

    incstr = strinc(str_num1, +1);
    printf("%s\n", incstr);//abc12346
    free(incstr);
    incstr = strinc("abcd12345", +1);
    printf("%s\n", incstr);//abcd12346
    free(incstr);
    incstr = strinc("abcd999", +1);
    printf("%s\n", incstr);//abcd1000
    decstr = strinc(incstr, -1);
    printf("%s\n", decstr);//abcd999
    free(incstr);
    free(decstr);

    return 0;
}
```